# Flutter/Dart: Convert date to yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'

Tags: flutter, date, datetime, dart

Trying to convert `DateTime.now()` to this: `2019-06-04T12:08:56.235-0700`

The API documentation insists that's Data format: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'` but I can't figure it out for Dart. Not even python for that matter.

I've tried `now.toIso8601String()` but it doesn't quite nail it (i.e. `2019-12-03T17:50:23.476164`). It's missing the last `-` section and one digit. The API call within flutter returns a `{code:415 message HTTP 415 Unsupported Media Type}` as a result.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @hata pointed out, it's not yet implemented. So, to add the Z (timezone as number) exactly as requested I did this:

```
String formatISOTime(DateTime date) {
    //converts date into the following format:
// or 2019-06-04T12:08:56.235-0700
    var duration = date.timeZoneOffset;
    if (duration.isNegative)
      return (DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmm").format(date) +
          "-${duration.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}${(duration.inMinutes - (duration.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}");
    else
      return (DateFormat("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.mmm").format(date) +
          "+${duration.inHours.toString().padLeft(2, '0')}${(duration.inMinutes - (duration.inHours * 60)).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}");
  }
```

Implemented:

```
  void main() {
    DateTime getCurrentTimestamp = DateTime.now();
    print('agreement signed');
    String agreementSigned = formatISOTime(getCurrentTimestamp);
    print(agreementSigned);
  }
```

When ran:

```
main();

// Result:

2021-10-29T17:53:56.053+0100
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, as for `intl/intl.dart` [DateFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) class, time zone has not been implemented yet.

> The following characters are reserved and currently are unimplemented:

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Example |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| z | time zone | (Text) | Pacific Standard Time |
| Z | time zone (RFC 822) | (Number) | -0800 |
| v | time zone (generic) | (Text) | Pacific Time |

Comment: Cheers for the heads up. Had to add it manually with `timeZoneOffset`